# How to have a working Textarea and a fileUpload in one form

Tags: newline, multipartform-data, websphere-liberty

### The Problem

The below test case illustrates my issue. I have a JSF application which uses a HTML form in which I must use enctype="multipart/form-data" since I am using a file upload, [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp). However when I use this encoding, newlines entered into my Textarea disappear when submitted to the server.

The text area in result.xhtml always shows all of the text the user entered on index.xhtml on one line, regardless of any newlines the user put in. The output text always evaluates to "False" to reflect that the backing property never receives any text with "\n" or "\r".

### Test Case

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:body>
            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{controller.text}"/>
                <h:inputFile value="#{controller.file}"/>

                <h:commandButton value="Upload and Continue" type = "submit" action="#{controller.respond}"/>
            </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Controller.java

```
package main;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@Named("controller")
@SessionScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String text;
    private boolean containsNewline = false;
    private Part file;

    public String respond() {
        return "result.xhtml";
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        if (value.contains("\n") || value.contains("\r")) {
            containsNewline = true;
        }
        text = value;
    }
    public String getText() {return text;}
    public String getContainsNewline()
    {
        return String.valueOf(containsNewline);
    }
    public void setFile(Part value) { file = value; }
    public Part getFile() { return file; }
}
```

result.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{controller.text}"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{controller.containsNewline}"/>
            </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

### My Theory

I read [RFC2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) and from what I understand, multipart/form-data has uses a sequence of characters to delimit Parts in the stream, and reading up on other blogs I saw that it is common to use newline characters as part of the delimiter. Is it possible that my newline characters from my Textarea are getting mixed up into the delimiter ?

The only other thing I can think of, is in RFC2388 4.5, each part is allowed to have its own content-type, which in the case of text data is the charset parameter. How do I set a different charset ? and which one do I use ?

I may even be completely off with the above, these are just my current theories.

### Technology I am using

I am using JSF 2.2 and CDI 1.2 running on Websphere Application Server 17.0.0.2. Upgrading to JSF 2.3 is not an option for me, I've already been down that path and ran into unsolvable issues, see these 2 questions on SO:
[implementing JSF-2.3 and CDI together in WebSphere Application Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109997/implementing-jsf-2-3-and-cdi-together-in-websphere-application-server) and [JSF-2.3 not finding my @Named CDI-1.2 managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064995/jsf-2-3-not-finding-my-named-cdi-1-2-managed-bean)

Comment: Question title should be 'how to have a working textArea and a fileUpload in one form. Otherwise a very valid answer would be: "Don't put them in one form"... Or... "remove the `enctype`... Did you try a simple example in e.g. Tomcat? You tagged it websphere-liberty, which indicates it specifically (only) fails in that server. How to explicitly set a charset to utf-8 for the form can be found in stackoverflow.

Comment: And like in the other Q...`if (value.contains("n") || value.contains("r"))` is strange... that should be \n \r

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to update the test case on my computer. Title changed, Never used Tomcat before but I'll test it in the coming days.

Comment: Will also test using a different charset

Comment: @Kukeltje Took me a while to get Tomcat working with JSF, but I have now tested on Tomcat 8.5 and the problem is **not** present on Tomcat, for some reason this only occurs on WAS...
I also tried adding `accept-charset="UTF-8"` and `accept-charset="8859-1"` to the `<form>` and it didn't help

Comment: I could not reproduce on Wildfly either. Did you use the same jsf implementation/version?

Comment: @Kukeltje I tested the test case on both WAS and Tomcat using the same jsf impl and version packaged in with the .war, and could only reproduce it on WAS

Comment: Ok, since I'm not a was user, things end for me here. Maybe file an issue with IBM. And maybe try to force a stacktrace and see if there are any unknown filters in the chain that might cause this.